# making searcher in prolog

Tags: search, prolog

I'm trying to build a searcher, where I have an inverted index, something like

indice("word1", [id1,id2,...,idN])

indice("word2", [id1,id2,...,idM])

Then, I have to search the id's of the words in a phrase, thinking that phrase is a list of words.

Predicade must be something like bestMatch(Phrase, Result), where result are the id's that make bestMatch true.

I make this program. When I use one word phrase, like bestMatch(["hello"], X), it give me X = [100] for example, but when I try usigin bestMatch(["hello", "stack], X), the program just give me false.

```
bestMatch([],Result).
bestMatch([Word|Xs], Result):-
    singleTermQuery(Word, L),
    append([], L, Result),
    bestMatch(Xs, Result).
```

I don't really know what is happening. I'm rookie in this paradigm. Hope can help me please.

Comment: I think you should post some test data...

Comment: `bestMatch([], any)` is true!

Comment: I'm sorry to say that you kind of lucked out that it seems to work with one word. Your predicates have several issues. As false mentioned, `bestMatch([], any)` succeeds and that's because `bestMatch([],Result).` succeeds for any `Result` value, unconditionally. So you need to rethink what your base case should be. Your predicate fails because the second clause `bestMatch([Word|Xs], Result):- ...` over-uses `Result`. You have `append([], L, Result)` (which is the same as `L = Result`), then `bestMatch(Xs, Result)` which must unify its result with the `Result` variable, which it can't.

Comment: How is your predicate related to your index (which you call `indice`)? Your predicate makes no reference to your data.